# Static Analyzer falsely finding an expression to be "always 0"

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, clang-static-analyzer

I have a property, noteName, declared as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) IVNoteName noteName;
```

and defined as follows:

```
@synthesize noteName;
```

but when I attempt to use it, the static analyzer behaves strangely.

```
NSInteger noteNameOffsets[8] = {0,2,3,5,7,8,10};
midiValue += noteNameOffsets[[self noteName]]; //On this line,
//the analyzer tells me "The right operand to '+=' is always 0"
```

I have logged the value of `[self noteName]` in that method call, finding many sensible, non-zero values. Furthermore, the method this code is from works as intended.

Comment: What is the value of `NSLog(@"%d", [self noteName]);`?

Comment: 2, 3, reasonable values. The method in question works as intended.

Comment: @andyvn22: What is the noteName method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue in Xcode 4.2.